# Copy and paste information from one worksheet to another within a workbook based on matching ID

Tags: vba, excel

I would need a code that would allow me to copy and paste the information based on the matching IDs. The problem is that the number of rows that both my sheets has is more than 200000 rows with IDs on each rows. Some of the IDs are repeated in sheet 2. I only manage to create a code but it seems to be running and then it crash. Sheet 2 consist of all the information while Sheet 1 is where the information will be pasted when the IDs from both sheets matched.
This is the code that i have so far. I really hope anyone could help me with this as this code seems to keep running and crash and my VBA skills is very limited,

```
Sub AAA()

  Dim tracker As Worksheet
    Dim master As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cellFound As Range
    Dim OutPut As Integer

   Set tracker = Workbooks("test.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set master = Workbooks("test.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")


    For Each cell In master.Range("A2:A100000")
        ' Try to find this value in the source sheet
        Set cellFound = tracker.Range("A5:A100000").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
            ' A matching value was found
            ' So copy the cell 2 columns across to the cell adjacent to matching value
            ' Do a "normal" copy & paste
            cellFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2 = cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2
            ' Or do a copy & paste special values
            'cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Copy
            'cellFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Else
            ' The value in this cell does not exist in the source
            ' Should anything be done?
        End If
    Next
    OutPut = MsgBox("Update over!", vbOKOnly, "Update Status")


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried your code on a smaller sample? Does it work there? Do you encounter any other problems?

Comment: Hi i did try in a smaller sample and it works but once i tried for more bigger sample like the above stated rows it keeps running. @Tom

Comment: In my experience you just have to deal with that. VBA is pretty slow when it comes to bigger sets of data. But: Is there any way to downsize your sample? Is it structured in a particular way so you could eliminate some of it? If so: try to describe it within your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by deallocating the variable `cellFound` before re-assigning it. So, I suggest that you add:

```
Set cellFound  = Nothing
```

right after the `End If`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi does it work for you when the code run for more than 10000 rows? Because i have already did what you told but it seems that my code still keeps running :( @Ralph

Comment: Yes, the above solution was able to help me with a sheet of roughly 500.000 rows. Yet, this was also the time that I realized that a DB server is better suited for that kind of work. Now I have an SQL server running which does the same in less than a second.

Comment: Why don't you insert a `Debug.Print cell.Address` after the `End If` in order to find out if your code is in an infinite loop or if your computer is just too slow to cope with this amount of data? Like this you could see if there is any progress.

Comment: How long does it take for the code to finish running? because i have around 200000 rows but i tried to run it for 100000 rows and it keeps running for more than 5 minutes thus, i decided to stop it. @Ralph and what do you mean by DB server is better suited for that kind of work?

Comment: i tried already and it does not show any error when i run it for less than 100 rows but if i tried for the 10000 rows it takes forever to run @Ralph

Comment: But it runs and `Debug.Print` is showing a progress? Well, then you just have a slow computer and should probably use a more efficient software to handle this amount of data. Once again, I can only suggest to get a DB server to do that. [MS SQL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx), [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html), [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/), or any other free DB server will do. For the amount of data you will need it for they are all free of charge.

Comment: Yeah it runs well with the Debug.Print with less than 1000 rows but when i did it for 100000 rows it take forever to run. I am currently using a business laptop, that is why i hope to find any code that would allow me to run it smoothly for more than 100000 rows @Ralph

Comment: @Nabilah: It seems that your original question is solved. You were seeking for a solution that wouldn't crash anymore. This has been solved and the question should be closed. If you are now seeking to optimize your code for the large amount of data then I suggest you open a new question. Yet, in this case you should also provide the entire code because it will be necessary to review the entire code for possible speed improvements.

Comment: That is the code that i have for now. Alright i will post another question then. Thank you @Ralph

Comment: @nabilah: You already did that. The question is closed and solved. You can see that due to the green check-mark next to my answer. For more information go to http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: I dont know how to close the question